# HIVESERVER2 ERROR

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've been trying to start hiveserver2 and I've searched a lot... but I couldn't find right one to solve my problem. I'm a newbie to hive. If anyone knows how to fix it please let me know. ~~

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF077.jpg)

Comment: How about telling _what_ error you've encountered?

Comment: I added a link for error image. plz click on the link and you can see the error

Comment: Please include the relevant information as text in the question itself, not as links to images. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Marc Thank you for the information I didn't know. I'll repost it.

Answer (score 0):

use this command, "sudo start hive-server2"